# Get selected row's invisible Id in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and I am trying to get selected row's Id (UrunId).Here is my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewHdcvi" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceHdcvi" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="UrunId">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sil">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteProduct" runat="server" Text="Satırı Sil" CommandName="deleteProduct">
                                                    </asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sil" Visible="false">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                   <%#Eval("UrunId") %>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>

                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ÜRÜN VE DETAYLARI">
                                                <ItemStyle Width="400px" />
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <div style="color: red" class="text-center"><%#Eval("UrunAdi") %></div>
                                                    <%#Eval("UrunDetay") %>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:ImageField HeaderText="ÜRÜN GÖRSELİ" DataImageUrlField="UrunResim"></asp:ImageField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BİRİM FİYAT">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <%#Eval("UrunFiyati") %>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ADET">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdet" runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>
```

As you can see I don't want user to see my "UrunId" column but when user clicks "deleteProduct", I need to get that row's UrunId in codebehind. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is the issue currently? Are you not able to delete the row? Can you show your delete method?

Comment: Just add `CommandArgument` in you link button. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .ASPX markup

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sil">
         <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteProduct" runat="server" Text="Satırı Sil" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("UrunId")%>' CommandName="deleteProduct" OnClick="LinkButton_Click">
               </asp:LinkButton>
          </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

> Code behind

```
  protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
      LinkButton btn=(LinkButton)sender;
      int Id= Convert.toInt32(btn.CommandArgument);
      //Your delete code here
  }
```

OR

```
protected void gridRowCommand(objectsender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int Id= Convert.toInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    //Your delete code here
}
```